# How do I place divs side by side?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is to place the divs next to each other rather than how they are that they stack over each other.

side note:

I want the divs to be side by side but start from the top right of the screen adding a new lists div or taking out some depending on the screen size, but to always start the divs from right to left at the top of the screen.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists1">
  <ul>
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
    <li>option 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="lists2">
  <ul>
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
    <li>option 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="lists3">
  <ul>
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
    <li>option 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ah mate its 2016 , you are going to want to look into flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `div` containers same class and add `float:right` on them in CSS like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/q6c34sqk/1/

EDIT: for more elegant solution use Flexbox:
https://jsfiddle.net/q6c34sqk/2/

```
<div class="main-contain">
  <div class="lists">
    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>option 2</li>
      <li>option 3</li>
      <li>option 9</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="lists">
    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>option 2</li>
      <li>option 3</li>
      <li>option 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="lists">
    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>option 2</li>
      <li>option 3</li>
      <li>option 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="lists">
    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>option 2</li>
      <li>option 3</li>
      <li>option 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-contain{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.lists {
  display: inline-block;
}
```